# Как через php можно проверить, работает ли прокси сервер?

Tags: php, сокет

Есть прокси сервера такого вида: "*.134.102.3:18542"

Как через php можно проверить, работает ли этот прокси сервер?

Можно ли как-то, используя fsockopen, сделать get запрос и проверить ответ?

Дело в том, что у меня большой файл с этими прокси серверами, и они должны постоянно обновлятся и выводить статуст(Работает/не отвечает) каждого прокси сервера. Скорось выполнения тоже имеет значение.

Без использования curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если не подходит cURL, то возможно воспользоваться вызовом fopen, используя [http_context](http://php.net/manual/ru/context.http.php) (там есть поддержака proxy).